# jqGrid Applying postdata filters in grid create ODD behavior

Tags: search, filter, jqgrid

I am seeing two different behaviors and not sure why. Parts of the question are result of testing solutions implemented from other Q & A.

Summarized Grid create(I only included properties pertinent to question)...

**grid setup1**

```
url: jqDataUrl,
datatype: "json",
mtype: "GET",

//loadonce: true

// Default sorting
sortname: typeof prefs.sortCol !== "undefined" ? prefs.sortCol : "LastName",
sortorder: typeof prefs.sortCol !== "undefined" ? prefs.sortOrd :  "asc",
sorttype: "text",
sortable: true,

postData: { filters: JSON.stringify({ "groupOp": "AND", "rules": [{ "field": "FirstName", "op": "cn", "data": "max" }]})},
search: true,
```

**results 1** with search: true

When the above grid first loads, it loads with filtered results from postdata filters. If I go to edit url of a resulting row and come back, the record in grid not updated, even though the page/grid above is reloading from scratch from server.

**grid setup 2**

```
//same as above but
search: false
```

**results 2** with search: false

When the grid loads this time, the filter not applied.  If I go to edit url of a row and come back, the record is updated.

---

I've read a lot of posts about setting loadonce: true, and changing datatype from local to json and json to local for refreshing, but what I want is for the grid to always load, sort and filter from server data.

Although I understand that free jqGrid does things better, unfortunately, I cannot replace current jqGrid.js file.

My question is two part:

1) I do not see search as an option on wiki [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) so where is it defined.

2) Can and how do I get the postdata filters to apply on load AND my records updated on the grid after edit?

Comment: So you use `loadonce: true` in the first scenario or not? Do you want apply filtering **locally** or **on the server**? Which `editurl` you use `"clientArray"` or some URL to the server? Which editing mode you use? You wrote "I cannot replace current jqGrid.js file", but you didn't wrote **which version and from which fork you use**. It's important to understand that you can't just change `datatype` from json to local at any time. It's important that you should fill `data` parameter at the time. Only if `data` parameter is filled then you can work with the grid like with local grid.

Comment: Not using loadonce: true. Just put uncommented above so it can be seen not used.  A row edit is sent to another page connected to server and save/cancel on that page reloads originating grid page, so I assume when grid reloads it should be getting latest data for grid, but does not. I guess one question is why does search:true applies postdata filters but does not allow grid page to load with new updated values, but instead shows old values until I hit refresh data button? And why does search: false not allow postdata filters to apply?

Comment: @Oleg I figured out results 1 issue above.  With search: true when I return from edit page the mvc controller was getting the data from session NOT querying the database for new data. The conditional to use session or database was based on some binded variable. Not sure what it's bound to, but commented it out and works as expected. Did not figure out search:false issue (results 2 above).  In the controller, the where clause for grid is populated with postdata filter, but all results are returned from query instead of filtered.  Very strange. Looking into more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own questions:

1) search:true will send _search==true in the http request.

2) The postdata filters(aka where clause when querying data) was being sent in the http request, however, my controller was performing different operations based upon the search: value(aka _search) parsed from http request.

Inside my controller I was setting another property based upon the _search value, and the controller's property was then used to determine whether or not to refresh grid data or use session.  It was using session and thus did not update my filtered results after edit.

Another issue I found, was that if I had search:true and manually reset postdata filters to {}, my controller had an error(non thrown w/o try/catch) when it tried to setup the linq with a null, and exited out of grid setup and displayed nothing.